# Where should I store scripts for the ExecuteScript processor in NiFi?

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

I've created a script to transform JSON and I want to use it with the ExecuteScript processor. What is the recommended location to store the script?

Processor interface:

[image: ExecuteProcessor]

NiFi directory:

[image: NiFi directory]

Comment: create a subfolder in the nifi root folder. for example `scripts`. and point to it as `./scripts/MyScript...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a standalone NiFi instance and want to keep your scripts on the filesystem, I second daggett's answer. If you have a NiFi cluster, you'd need to make the script available in that location for each node in the cluster, which can be a pain to maintain.

Alternatively you can keep the actual script body in the processor itself (in the Script Body property), but any updates to the script have to be done there rather than the disk version. So there's a tradeoff re: maintainability.

Comment: What if you put the configuration in a distributed file system like GlusterFS?

Comment: That will work but it will go out to the FS every time it needs to load the script. That shouldn’t be too often (i.e. only on processor restart?) but it is something to be aware of with respect to performance.

Comment: @mattyb i have 3 node cluster. i use ExecuteScript processor to write some information about each files generated into the single file maintained in the local disk cluster. though i have set Execution value as "All Nodes", the files are not writing to all the nodes.

Comment: @natarajank this will be better answered as a separate SO question